# Why are these pointers the same, while referring to different instances of an object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, copy-constructor

I am debugging a copy constructor I created for a binary search tree, I'm doing this by monitoring the memory addresses of the nodes in the original tree as well as in the newly created copy. A node consists of a pointer to a Comparable item (which contains only a single char), a count of occurrences of that char, and pointers to its child nodes (or `nullptr`).

```
  struct Node {
    int count; // the number of occurences of the Comparable item (a char in this case)
    Comparable* item; // the Comparable item being tracked
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
  };
```

Here is my copy constructor and helper:

```
BST::BST(const BST& tree)
{
  rootPtr = copy(tree.rootPtr);
}

BST::Node* BST::copy(Node* root)
{
  if (root == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  Node* temp = new Node;
  Comparable* ptr = new Comparable;
  *ptr = *root->item;

  temp->item = ptr;
  temp->count = root->count;
  temp->rightChild = copy(root->rightChild);
  temp->leftChild = copy(root->leftChild);

  return temp;
}
```

I am outputting the data from both trees, as well as their addresses in memory, to the console using this function:

```
void BST::printInOrder(Node* root) const
{ 
  if (root->leftChild != nullptr) {
    printInOrder(root->leftChild);
  }

  cout << "&root: " << &root << " root: " << root << " :: " << *root->item << " " << root->count << endl;
  // example output: &root: 00EFF388 root: 0113E858 :: W 1

  if (root->rightChild != nullptr) {
    printInOrder(root->rightChild); 
  }
}
```

Here is the console output for the original tree (top) and the tree constructed by the copy constructor (bottom):

```
  // original tree
    &root: 00EFF470     root: 01140760 :: ! 1
    &root: 00EFF558     root: 0113A018 :: H 1
    &root: 00EFF388     root: 0113E858 :: W 1
    &root: 00EFF2A0     root: 011406F0 :: d 1
    &root: 00EFF470     root: 01134940 :: e 1
    &root: 00EFF388     root: 01134A80 :: l 3
    &root: 00EFF2A0     root: 0113E7E8 :: o 2
    &root: 00EFF1B8     root: 01140680 :: r 1
    
  // copy of original tree
    &root: 00EFF470     root: 01140F90 :: ! 1
    &root: 00EFF558     root: 011407A0 :: H 1
    &root: 00EFF388     root: 01141390 :: W 1
    &root: 00EFF2A0     root: 01140C90 :: d 1
    &root: 00EFF470     root: 01140BE8 :: e 1
    &root: 00EFF388     root: 011410D0 :: l 3
    &root: 00EFF2A0     root: 01140E10 :: o 2
    &root: 00EFF1B8     root: 01140DD0 :: r 1
```

You will notice that for both trees the second column (`root:`) contains a completely different set of memory addresses from the first tree to the second, this makes sense and leads me to believe my copy constructor is working correctly as the Node* pointers are pointing to different addresses in memory (while those addresses contain identical values).

The first column, (`&root:`), is where my confusion lies. I don't understand why nodes from both trees would have their pointers pointed to by the same pointer (this is better suited for a diagram).

```
//column 1:              //column 2:
//identical addresses    //different addresses
&root: 00EFF470          root: 01140760 :: ! 1
&root: 00EFF470          root: 01140F90 :: ! 1
```

Any insight or direction on where to look into this more would be helpful, I'm certainly a novice C++'er, oh, and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 if that makes a difference for this.

Comment: Show your code that creates/copy/print the tree too. Just the function is not enough to run the program.

Comment: What happens if you change `void BST::printInOrder(Node* root) const` to `void BST::printInOrder(Node*& root) const`? (I cannot test it because your code is not a [mre].)

Comment: When you print `&root` you print the location of the local variable `root`, which is totally separate from the tree or the nodes in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&root` is the address of the variable root.  The variable root is a pointer, but that pointer exists on the stack.

So a pointer is like a piece of paper with a street address on it.  `root` is a piece of paper with the address of `*root` on it.

`&root` is **where that piece of paper is**.  The stack is like a special road where you build and destroy "local" variable storage all the time.  `root`, the piece of paper, is in that local stack street.  `&root` is the address of that piece of paper on the local stack "street".

Every time you call a function, some space is reserved on the stack for its local variables and arguments.  When the function call is done, that space is reused.

Because the stack is reused, two different functions will use the same memory -- the same address -- to store different data.  This happens when you call one function, let it return, then call the other function.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me get my head around it. So if I had not called 
 ```printInOrder``` for the second tree immediately after I called it for the first tree I could have potentially used different memory addresses when I did finally call ```printInOrder``` on the second tree?

Actually, don't answer that, I'm going to play with it myself and see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Here are the key lines from your code:

```
void BST::printInOrder(Node* root) const
{ 

  cout << "&root: " ...
```

Inspect only these lines, just look at these two lines, and then ask yourself the following question:

> What is `&root`

Think of this as a pop quiz. Give yourself five seconds to come up with an answer, before reading the answer below:

...

`&root` is, of course, the address of the "root" parameter to the `printInOrder`. So, when you called this function twice, to print two different binary trees, it just so happened that in both function calls the parameter happened to be at the same memory address, in automatic scope. And that's why you see the same memory address, each time.

Perhaps you meant to pass a ***reference*** to the root node, as this parameter?

In other words:

```
void BST::printInOrder(Node *& root) const
```